# The only way to increase Champion Levels are through fights, right? There's no Orb or anything to boost it faster?

Tags: gems-of-war

The only way to increase Champion Levels are through fights, right? There's no Orb or anything to boost it faster?

Unlike Class Levels, or Trait Levels...

The only way to go faster, is if a player can do 2 Champion EXP Fights, like the Challenge Fights, faster than 2 of the 1 Champion EXP ones, a.k.a the regular quest and Explore fights?

...

And I just saw Class Trials in the Games section, which the game doesn't notify me about because I haven't unlocked the class, I assume...

Comment: You can get class battles, generally every Tuesday of the week. Push that HARD to push up your classes - And *no*, you DON'T need to unlock the Class Quest in the Kingdom, first... you can do it as the very first step in the day-long Class event, every week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, Class Trials are the alternative way to get champion XP. If you are very, very spendy, you can fully upgrade a class that way, but it is very expensive (5290 gems) and not recommended. So yes, you will have to make up the remaining champion XP via battles.

Class Trials for existing classes are scheduled every Thursday, for 24 hours. (New Class Trials operate on a different schedule, but there are no new classes anticipated any time soon.)

You can unlock the class quest from the Class Trial itself; you do not have to complete the corresponding kingdom quest first.

Comment: IIRC, when booting up the game, I've only seen clear notifications for Games, for Pet Rescue... Are notifications for Class Trials bundled in the Weekly Info or whatever, the tabbed information on bootup?

Comment: It's listed in the Games menu of the game. But mostly, experienced players know the weekly event calendar: Monday: nothing; Tuesday: Faction Assault; Wednesday: Pet Rescue; Thursday: Class Trial; Friday through Sunday: usually, some weekend event.

Answer (score 0):

You can get class battles, generally every Tuesday of the week. Push that HARD to push up your classes - And *no*, you DON'T need to unlock the Class Quest in the Kingdom, first... you can do it as the very first step in the day-long Class event, every week.